# Dataframe modification with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have an input csv file like below

[image]

and the output should be like this

[image]

How to achieve this using pandas?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `as_index=False`

```
new_df = (df.assign(**df[['column2', 'column3']].astype(str))
            .melt('column1', 
                  value_vars=['column_2', 'column_3'], 
                  value_name='column_2')
            .groupby("column_1", as_index=False)[['column_2']]
            .agg( "|".join))
```

[`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) is used to be able to change the type of the columns to string dynamically by **selecting only columns 2 and 3**.

It might be necessary if `column1` is not string at some point

Answer (score 1):

try this, [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to transform given DataFrame from wide format to long format, [`groupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply) to join the values.

```
import pandas as pd

(
    pd.melt(df, id_vars="column_1",
            value_vars=['column_2', 'column_3'], value_name='column_2')
        .astype(str)
        .groupby("column_1")['column_2']
        .apply(lambda x: "|".join(x)).reset_index()
)
```